# VBA Appication-defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Thanks in advance for anyone's time.  I've scoured the site for various examples of my error statement, but the common theme seems to be an improper reference, which I assume is my error but haven't found it yet.  I also wonder if I've defined any of my variables incorrectly.

This is a procedure to look at two different worksheets within one workbook. Individual IDs reside in column A in both sheets.  The procedure should check if IDs match, then check if the current date in CurrentHx sheet is within the start and stop dates for that medication entry in SzConMeds sheet.  If so, it adds the name of the medication to the the output variable.  IF not, it moves to the next SzConMeds sheet row.  This dummy data set has only 500 rows in each sheet.

```
Option Explicit 'declares all variables
Option Compare Text 'Makes case insensitive
Sub MatchingParticipantIDs()
Dim r As Long 'CurrentHx row counter variable
Dim s As Long 'SzConMeds row counter variable
Dim Med As String 'output in CurrentHx for what ASMs taking at that visit date
Dim LastHxRow As Long 'Last row in CurrentHx worksheet
Dim LastMedRow As Long 'Last row in SzConMed worksheet
Dim CurrentVisitDate As Date 'Date of Current Visit in CurrentHx worksheet
Dim MedStartDate As Date 'Date of ASM start in SzConMed worksheet
Dim MedStopDate As Date 'Date of ASM stop in SzConMed worksheet
Dim SzMedName As String 'Name of the ASM in the SzConMed worksheet
Dim CurrentHxMedOutput As Long 'The location for the output "Med" variable
Dim CurrentHxID As String
Dim SzConMedsID As String

Workbooks("DummyData.xlsm").Activate
LastHxRow = 500
LastMedRow = 500
CurrentVisitDate = Worksheets("CurrentHx").Range("I" & r).Value
MedStartDate = Worksheets("SzConMeds").Range("G" & s).Value
MedStopDate = Worksheets("SzConMeds").Range("M" & s).Value
SzMedName = Worksheets("SzConMeds").Range("N" & s).Value 
CurrentHxMedOutput = Worksheets("CurrentHx").Range("N" & r).Value
CurrentHxID = Worksheets("CurrentHx").Range("A" & r).Value
SzConMedsID = Worksheets("SzConMeds").Range("A" & s).Value

Med = " "
For r = 2 To LastHxRow 'each row in CurrentHx
    For s = 2 To LastMedRow 'each row in SzConMeds
        If CurrentHxID = SzConMedsID Then
            If DateValue(CurrentVisitDate) > DateValue(MedStartDate) And DateValue(MedStopDate) > DateValue(CurrentVisitDate) Then 
                Med = Med & ", " & SzMedName
            ElseIf DateValue(CurrentVisitDate) > DateValue(MedStartDate) And MedStopDate = "WAS BLANK" Then
                Med = Med & ", " & SzMedName
            End If
        End If
    Next s 'Check the next ID in SzMeds 
    CurrentHxMedOutput = Med
    Med = " " 'Clears the Med variable prior to the next CurrentHx row
Next r 
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? Also `Med` is a `String`, `CurrentHxMedOutput` is a `Long`, and you try to do `CurrentHxMedOutput = Med`? And `MedStopDate` is a `Date` but you check if it `= "WAS BLANK"`?

Comment: And `r` and `s` are 0 when you try to do `CurrentVisitDate = Worksheets("CurrentHx").Range("I" & r).Value`, `MedStartDate = Worksheets("SzConMeds").Range("G" & s).Value`, etc. Read the values *inside* your `For` loops.

Comment: This is so incredibly helpful!  I am a total novice (other than an ForDummies book and a lot of SO), so thank you so much.    Some answers: I ran early data cleaning on the Stop Date field and added "WAS BLANK" if it was blank because the medication was continuing, but I can see how that completely affects how I dimension that variable. CurrentMedOutput should 100% be string.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem - we were all novices at one point.

Comment: @BigBenYour second comment is probably very helpful; I also don't yet fully understand what you are saying.  I tried to make the row counter variables "r" and "s" start at 2 since the first row is column titles.  When you say "Read the values inside your For loops," do you mean add a debug.print r line and watch the values in the immediate window?

Comment: Yeah I should have been slightly more clear. If you don't give `r` and `s` a value, the default value `0` is used. The `CurrentVisitDate = ..`, `MedStartDate = ...` , etc., lines are outside your loop - so `r` and `s` have the default value of `0`, which will throw an error - Range("I0") doesn't exist, right? So move any lines using `r` and `s` within your loops, where you are actually giving `r` and `s` a value - 2, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: Brilliant.  Can't wait.  I'll run it now and see how it goes. Again, thanks.

Comment: For anyone learning from this example: I ultimately resolved the issue by changing my CurrentVisitDate variables to object variables (ie. Set CurrentVisitDate = Worksheets("CurrentHx").Range("I" & r)), dimensioning them as Range, and changing the actual procedure to be CurrentVisitDate.Value.  I was clearly making some kind of dimensioning and/or defining errors.  Thanks, all!